# Celery task PENDING

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery, python-multithreading, celery-task

I basically want to be able to create a `chord` consisting of a `group` of `chains`. Beyond the fact that I can't seem to make that work is the fact that all the sub-chains have to complete before the chord callback is fired.

So my thought was to create a `while` loop like:

```
data = [foo.delay(i) for i in bar]
complete = {}
L = len(data)
cnt = 0
while cnt != L:
    for i in data:
        ID = i.task_id
        try:
            complete[ID]
        except KeyError:
            if i.status == 'SUCCESS':
                complete[ID] = run_hourly.delay(i.result)
                cnt += 1
                if cnt >= L:
                    return complete.values()
```

So that when a task was ready it could be acted on without having to wait on other tasks to be complete.

The problem I'm having is that the status of some tasks never get past the `'PENDING'` state.

All tasks will reach the '`SUCCESS'` state if I add a `time.sleep(x)` line to the `for loop` but with a large number of `sub tasks` in `data` that solution becomes grossly inefficient.

I'm using memcached as my results backend and rabbitmq. My guess is that the speed of the for loop that iterates over `data` and calling attributes of it's tasks creates a race condition that breaks the connection to celery's messaging which leaves these zombie tasks that stay in the `'PENDING'` state. But then again I could be completely wrong and it certainly wouldn't be the first time..

**My questions**

Why is `time.sleep(foo)` needed to avoid a perpetually `PENDING` task when iterating over a list of just launched tasks?

When a celery task is performing a loop is it blocking? When I try to shutdown the worker that gets stuck in an infinite loop I am unable to do so and have to manually find the python process running the worker and kill it. If I leave the worker to run eventually the python process running it will start to consume several gigs of memory, growing exponentially and what seems to be without bound.

Any insight on this matter would be appreciated. I'm also open to suggestions on ways to avoid the `while loop` entirely.

I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: Well it won't help you a lot, but you should stick to use `chord` (or just a `group` with a `callback`), because it's exactly what you need here. If it's not working, something else is wrong (inside your tasks, your settings, etc...),for instance make sure you don't ignore the results in your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `chord` consisting of a `group` of `chains` was being constructed and executed from within a celery task. Which will create problems if you need to access the results of those tasks. Below is a summary of what I was trying to do, what I ended up doing, and what I think I learned in the processes so maybe it can help someone else.

--common_tasks.py--

```
from cel_test.celery import app

@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def qry(sql, writing=False):
    import psycopg2
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='space_test', user='foo', host='localhost')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    if writing == True:
        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return

    a = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return a
```

--foo_tasks.py --

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import chain, chord, group
import celery
from cel_test.celery import app
from weather.parse_weather import parse_weather
from cel_test.common_tasks import qry
import cPickle as PKL
import csv
import requests


@app.task(ignore_results=False)
def write_the_csv(data, file_name, sql):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        for i in data:
            a.writerows(i)
    qry.delay(sql, True)
    return True

@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def idx_point_qry(DIR='/bar/foo/'):
    with open(''.join([DIR, 'thing.pkl']), 'rb') as f:
            a = PKL.load(f)
    return [(i, a[i]) for i in a]

@app.task(ignore_results=False)
def load_page(url):
    page = requests.get(url, **{'timeout': 30})
    if page.status_code == 200:
        return page.json()

@app.task(ignore_results=False)
def run_hourly(page, info):
    return parse_weather(page, info).hourly()

@app.task(ignore_results=False)
def pool_loop(info):
    data = []
    for iz in info:
        a = chain(load_page.s(url, iz), run_hourly.s())()
        data.append(a)
    return data



@app.task(ignore_results=False)
def run_update(file_name, sql, writing=True):
    chain(idx_point_qry.s(), pool_loop.s(file_name, sql), write_the_csv.s(writing, sql))()
    return True
```

--- separate.py file ---

```
from foo_tasks import *

def update_hourly_weather():
    fn = '/weather/csv_data/hourly_weather.csv'
    run_update.delay(fn, "SELECT * from hourly_weather();")
    return True

update_hourly_weather()
```

I tried 30 or so combinations of .py files listed above along with several combinations of the code existing in them. I tried `chords`, `groups`, `chains`, launching tasks from different tasks, combining tasks.

A few combinations did end up working but I had to call `.get()` directly in the `wrtie_the_csv` task on `data` but celery was throwing a `warning` that in 4.0 calling get() in a task would raise an error so I thought I ought not to be doing that..

In essence my problem was (and still is) poor design of tasks and the flow between them. Which was leading me to the problem of having synchronize tasks from within other tasks.

The while loop I proposed in my question was an attempt to asynchronously launch tasks when another tasks status had become `COMPLETE` and then launch another task when that task had become complete and so on.. as opposed to synchronously letting celery do so through a call to `chord` or `chain`. What I seemed to find (and I'm not sure I'm right about this) was that from within a celery task you don't have access to the scope needed to discern such things. The following is a quote from the [state portion in the celery documentation on tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) “asserting the world is the responsibility of the task”.

I was launching tasks that the task had no idea existed and as such was unable to know anything about them.

My solution was the to load and iterate through the `.pkl` file and launch a group of `chains` with a callback synchronously. I basically replaced the `pool_loop` task with the code below and launched the tasks synchronously instead of asynchronously.

--the_end.py--

```
from foo_tasks import *
from common_tasks import *

def update_hourly_weather():
    fn = '/weather/csv_data/hourly_weather.csv'
    dd = []
    idx = idx_point_qry()
    for i in idx:
        dd.append(chain(load_page.s(i, run_hourly.s(i)))
    vv = chord(dd)(write_the_csv.s(fn, "SELECT * from hourly_weather();"))
    return

update_hourly_weather()
```